# SQL Server Default Collation vs DB with diffrent collation. Potential problems

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling with the design of new DB that has to be in different collation (Y Collation) that SQL Server Instance default collation (X Collation).
I'm looking for potential problems.

Temp Tables by default will be created with X Collation so any joins on text data types will fail unless I create temp table with Y collations on cols.

What comes to SQL Server text functions Replace, Substring etc. They will be always returned in X collation? What in case when I use REPLACE(...) COLLATE Y, do you see any potential data loss or maybe any different problems?

Comment: This has been the source of so much annoyance over the years. While for a small subset of users variable collation sequences is vital, for the rest of us its just a PITA. Personally I think MS should have made it optional! Having said that, I dont think you would lose data, I believe its purely in text comparison (including those used inside a replace) and sorting that it comes up. And yes, temp tables is one of the many places it comes up. I always add `collate database_default` wherever it does to set any external data to the same as the database I'm operating in.

Comment: The text functions always use the collation of the input expressions, and literals always have the collation of the current database, so that at least is rarely an issue. Explicit collation overrides are really only necessary on temp tables (and other data coming or going to another database). As an alternative to temp tables you can also consider using table variables, as those also take the collation of the current database.